# Проигрывание медиа файла во время загрузки

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage, аудио, mp3, windows-phone-7

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Есть ли способ начаться проигрывание медиа-файла в Windows Phone, пока еще идет его загрузка?

На данный момент у меня есть приложение, с возможностью загрузки и проигрывания медиа файлов.(Подобное описанно в [этой](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=586) статье)

Конкретно: сначала идет загрузка медиа файла, а уже потом, после полной загрузки, в `mediaElement.source` пишется путь к загружаемому потоку isolatedStorageFileStream. После чего файл можно уже воспроизвести.

А хочется сделать лучше - дать возможность проигрывать файл, когда загрузка еще идет. В конечном итоге, это будет выглядеть примерно так: идет загрузка файла, параллельно идет дешифровка этого файла, параллельно этот файл уже можно начать проигрывать. Про дешифровку пока забудем :),  тем более что для готового файла я ее уже написал. Осталось понять, что делать с проигрыванием.

Насколько я понял, `mediaElement` позволяет передавать в `source` только "цельные" файлы, без возможности в этот файл что-то дописывать. Возможно, при загрузке, надо сразу брать медиа из потока, а не из файла, куда пишется, не знаю, я в этом деле нуб.

Как можно такое реализовать? Что использовать для проигрывания медиа, т.к. `mediaElement`, похоже, не подходит.

Пока процесс загрузки реализован так:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(link));
```

Далее в OpenReadCompleted находится загруженный файл и

```
mediaFile.SetSource(isolatedStorageFileStream);
```

P.S. По умолчанию считаем, что работаем только с аудио-файлами формата mp3, никакого видео нет.

---

Есть, например, такая мысль. При запуске страницы с mediaElement-ом проверять, есть ли такой файл в IsolatedStorage. Если есть, то выполнять последовательность, описанную выше, если нет, то одновременно начать загрузку файла в IsolatedStorage и использовать что-нибудь для проигрывания потока, типа Background Audio Agent-а (правда этот поток еще и расшифровывать придется сразу же...).

Это вообще реально сделать, или я уже ухожу в магию? С Background Audio Agent-ом дел до текущего момента не имел, как с ним работать, пока без понятия, это были сугубо теоретические размышления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос висит уже довольно давно, пора закрывать.

Итак, вопрос был:

> "Есть ли способ начаться проигрывание
> медиа-файла в Windows Phone, пока еще
> идет его загрузка?"

Ответ: Нет

*"The MediaElement does not supporting streaming at the moment. It loads the entire file first before it actually plays it."*

[sarcasm mode on]

Короче, ребята из Microsoft работают над этим.

[sarcasm mode off]