# Баг Visual Studio? (file or assembly name X or one of its dependencies was not found)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Пытаюсь решить эту проблему: [Проигрывание медиа файла во время загрузки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/130355/181472)

Решил использовать AudioPlayerAgent. Скачал тестовый проект с MSDN, посмотрел, как он работает и(вот зачем?) подсоединил тестовый проект MyAudioPlayBackAgent(т.е. *csproj файл) к своему основному решению. После чего добавил ссылку на проект в решении и благополучно получил баг, т.к. на проект ссылаются два решения - тестовое и основное(не помню уже название бага, но на MSDN он точно описан).

Решил эту проблему так: ссылку на старый проект выкинул из основного решения нафиг, быстро набросал свой проект типа AudioPlayerAgent и залинковал в основной проект уже его. Однако неожиданно получил следующий баг:

При попытке вызвать конструктор класса из нового проекта(класс называется как-то вроде AudioPlaybackAgentX) внезапно вылезает следущее:

[image]

MyAudioPlayBackAgent это название assembly старого проекта(который был скачан с MSDN). Откуда Visual Studio берет эту ссылку? Я даже с помощью reflector-а не смог это найти. Ведь ссылка на старый проект уже давно удалена.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решил проблему. Похоже на редкостный идиотизм мелкомягких.

Судите сами:

В Windows Phone проекте есть Application Manifest файл "WMAppManifest.xml".
Так вот, там есть секция

```
<ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
```

При удалении ссылки на проект с BackgroundTask агентом запись об этом агенте оттуда *не удаляется*. То есть совсем. Она там тупо остается. В итоге, получается примерно следующее:
[image]

Как говорит нам Капитан Очевидность, ссылка была добавлена в проект четыре раза. А ниже - еще три ссылки на новый проект. Вам уже смешно? Мне - да.